# Xcode 5 UIButton Line break Word-Wrap Auto Layout constraints not working

Tags: xcode, uibutton, autolayout, word-wrap

I am having trouble with UIButtons that use word wrap and multiple lines of text. The trouble is getting the Auto Layout to enforce spacing between multiple UIButtons where some of the UIButtons are updated to have multiple lines of text. Basically the lines overlap because the buttons are not being moved apart.

Comment: Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34228276/4769344

Override intrinsicContentSize and layoutSubviews.