# Overlapping multi-line UIButtons

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, constraints

I am trying to put 5 Buttons in a `UIViewController`, which will have multi-line text:

[image: Setup 1]

But, when I set the multi-line content, text starts to overlap:

[image]

Are my constraints wrong? Should I do something else? Appreciate your help.

Comment: There's a number of posts here that address similar answers.  Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34228276/3487310) and [this](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/advanced-auto-layout-toolbox/#intrinsic-content-size-of-multi-line-text).  I'm not marking this question as a duplicate because I don't know if these answers will work.

Comment: What is your constraint for the bottom button? Is it left unconstrained from the bottom of your screen or is it constrained to the bottom? Are you seeing any messages in your console output that say the constraint engine can't satisfy all constraints so it is breaking one?

Comment: @WillM. it is left unconstrained, there is no message