# Multiline UIButton's title label is larger than the tapable area

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I have a UIButton where the height must be able to grow according to the title that the button is given (dynamically).

I've set the button's title label to have `numberOfLines = 0`, and set the `LineBreakMode` to `Word Wrap`. As a result, the button's text wraps as expected, but the button itself (I.E the tappable area) is not resized. See the following screenshot:

[image]

In this screenshot, the button's background colour is light gray to illustrate my point. As you can see, the button's title label (the blue text) is much larger than the background of the button. The button is constrained to be centred vertically and its leading/trailing anchors pinned to the superview so there is no constraint on it's height.

Am I missing a setting or trick that enables the button's area to grow relative to the title label?

Comment: set equal height constraint for button and label

Comment: This is the UIButton's default title label, rather than a separate label that I've added myself. I would have thought that the button would intrinsically size to fit the label.

Comment: Create a custom class of UIButton and add set the intrinsic content size of button and add code,  var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: titleLabel?.frame?.size?.height)!
}

Comment: Please try my code

Comment: This post has an excellent solution - even shows how to use this as `@IBDesignable` so you can see the auto-sizing at design-time. I added an answer in that post with Swift 3 updates.

Comment: @SaurabhJain, I wanted to avoid overriding the intrinsic content size of the button if possible. This seemed like something that a UIButton should be capable of without subclassing!

Comment: Whoops - I forgot to add the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845982/multiline-uibutton-and-autolayout/45715643#45715643