# Multiline multicolor attributed text in swift

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

How can I build something like this using attributed text? I tried adding line feed (\n), it didn't work, just displayed first line and cropped next two, removing \n will display two parts in single line:

```
let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

let regularAttribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 45.0), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.yellow]
let boldAttribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 25.0), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]     

let mutableAttributedString2 = NSMutableAttributedString()
let boldAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "person", attributes: boldAttribute)
let regularAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(self.requestCount)", attributes: regularAttribute)
mutableAttributedString2.append(boldAttributedString)
mutableAttributedString2.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n"))
mutableAttributedString2.append(regularAttributedString)

self.btnStatsPeople.setAttributedTitle(mutableAttributedString2, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Is your issue related to `UIButton`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604632/how-do-you-add-multi-line-text-to-a-uibutton ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845982/multiline-uibutton-and-autolayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel has one [line](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620539-numberoflines) by default.

> This property controls the maximum number of lines to use in order to
>   fit the label’s text into its bounding rectangle. The default value
>   for this property is 1. To remove any maximum limit, and use as many
>   lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0.

UIButton creates default UILabel. So using 0 lines is a solution for your problem:

```
self.btnStatsPeople.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```