# Autosizing superview height according to tallest subview button

Tags: ios, autolayout, ios-autolayout

[image]

I have following layout. The yellow view is a `buttonsContainerView` which acts as a container for 3 equal width buttons that it holds. All the three buttons are subview of yellow coloured `buttonsContainerView`. All the constraint that I have given are basic and visible and understandable in screenshot but still I will explain them below.

- `buttonsContainerView` - (yellow view) Pinned to top of `viewController`'s `view`'s `safeArea` with an inset of `20`. It's leading and trailing are pinned to `view`'s leading and trailing.
- `Button 1` - Top, bottom and leading pinned to `buttonContainerView`'s top, bottom and leading respectively. Trailing pinned to `Button 2`'s leading.
- `Button 2` - Top, bottom pinned to `buttonsContainerView`'s top and bottom respectively. Leading pinned to `Button 1` trailing. Trailing pinned to `Button 3`'s leading.
- `Button 3` - Top, bottom and trailing pinned to `buttonsContainerView`'s top, bottom and trailing respectively. Leading pinned to `Button 2`'s trailing.
- **Equal widths** - All three buttons are given equal width constraint with each other.

***Problem*** - Any of these three buttons may get a longer title dynamically and according to various phone screen sizes it may not accommodate in single line. I want my `buttonsContainerView`'s height to resize its height according to the tallest button, i.e., button with longest title hence greater height (In screenshot - `Button 2`, the centre button). In my case, `buttonsContainerView` is taking up height of smallest button (Button 1 and Button 2 in screenshot). How do I achieve this using AutoLayouts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline UIButton and autolayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845982/multiline-uibutton-and-autolayout)

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated your setup and can't find any problem with it, here is the picture below, can you show more info about this buttons setup? or maybe try to remove them and add again: [image]

Comment: Not working for me. Tried removing all constraints and re-adding them. Can you please run your code and confirm it work the same way as in your screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can  achieve this by  using combination of top insets constraints  by next algorithm:
1. Add to buttons horizontal constraints (left, right, same width).
2. Add a center vertically constraints for all buttons.
3. Add top inset constraints with **low** **priority** for all buttons.
4. Add greater or equal top insets for all buttons with **hight** **priority**.

Main idea is in low priority constraints for vertical insets of the buttons, the autolayout engine will try to satisfy it,  but the greater or equal top insets will prevent to do it for small buttons.

[image]

[image]